# How to run lib curl in Visual Studio 2013 from your project?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, libcurl

I have my Python (Flask) project set up and running on Visual studio 2013 for building REST API. For my client, I want to use lib curl however don't have any clue how to and where to type in the commands for curl?
example: curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Answer (score 0):

Download this (http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and you can use a terminal window....